# free allocated char* multiple times in C

Tags: c, pointers, char, malloc, free

i have this code in C:

```
 char* func(char* str, int a) {
        str = malloc(a * sizeof(char));
        return str;
    }
    int main() {
        char* s1 = NULL;
        s1 = func(s1,4);
        s1 = "123";
        free(s1);
        s1 = func(s1, 5);
        s1 = "1234";
        free(s1);
        ...
    }
```

i keep getting run time error(as if it were an infinte loop)

is this using of `s1` in `main()` legal?
would it produce memory leakage?

Comment: What runtime error is that? why do you think it behaves as if it was an infinite loop?

Comment: Again. If `s1 = func()` assigned a pointer to `s1` (which it does), then why would `s2 = "123"` **copy** the contents of the string? It doesn't. It's just another pointer assignment.

Comment: @iharob:by run time error, i mean that i dont see any otput on the screen, but rather an error telling me that my <program>.exe has stopped working

i did `s1 = "123"` to put value to the string, since `malloc` only allocates memory with rubbish data in it

Comment: Yes but `s1 = "123";` means `s1` points to the address of the literal `"123"` which is on the stack, hence when doing `free(s1);` you get a segmentation fault. @IvayloStrandjev gave you the correct answer for what you want to do. Still it appears that you don't understand dynamic memory allocation in C. So you must read about it.

Answer (score 5):

`s1 = "123";` here you make `s1` to point to a string literal and you should never call `free` for a string literal. My guess is that you meant to copy these characters to the memory allocated for `s1`. If that is the case, make use of [strcpy](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcpy/). For instance:

```
char* func(char* str, int a) {
    str = malloc(a * sizeof(char));
    return str;
}
int main() {
    char* s1 = NULL;
    s1 = func(s1,4);
    strcpy(s1, "123");
    free(s1);
    s1 = func(s1, 5);
    strcpy(s1, "1234");
    free(s1);
    ...
}
```

As for your second question - you have a memory leak in your code but precisely because of the reason I already mentioned - `s1 = "123";` does not copy the bytes but points `s1` at the literal. The code I suggest should be safe of memory leaks.

Comment: so you are saying that freeing `s1` multiple times doesn't mean you cant use it after every `free()`?
could you explain how "freeing" `s1` is legal?
and generally, is this habit of coding right or wrong?

Comment: @ThunderWiring It isn't technically used after each free, since it is assigned a new value by calling the `func` function that returns the address of newly allocated memory.

Answer (score 1):

You are freeing a string literal, and you loose the address `s1` points to when you do `s1 = "123";` and now you can never `free` it.

> is this using of s1 in main() legal? would it produce memory leakage? \

it will compile but it is not an issue of ilegal use but incorrect use, and yes it is an evident memory leak.

Comment: I'am sorry for the english mistakes, thank you @Codor.